# Publishing an Excel Spreadsheet Online

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working with a client that uses very sophisticated excel spreadsheets for generating purchase orders. They would like to place these online so a dealer could use it to submit a purchase order on their own.

Is there a way to disable editing of fields that have formulas attached to them so pricing can't be manipulated?

Comment: As @Mew said, a much better option would be to leave the sheet itself behind a *real* password, and build a form that the client interacts with to pass values to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can lock the cells containing the formulae and then protect the worksheet and set a password to unprotect it. The protection options allow you to disable editing (or even selecting) of locked cells.

Comment: It's [laughably easy](http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/removepwords.html) to override Excel password protection.